# Unable to rbind in R - Inspite of equal number of columns in all files

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, lapply, rbind

I am trying to read multiple csv files and finally create a dataframe out of it. However, my rbind was working fine till an hour back. But now, I am getting the usual rbind error indicating different number of columns.

I have around 14-17 csv files in a folder and am trying to read only files that start with "La". I am able to read them successfully but when I tried to rbind them, I am encountering the below error as shown in screenshot below. Please note that the code was working fine before an hour back. I tried restarting the Rstudio and doing it again but it results in the same error. Can you please help?

[image: Only read files that start with 'La']

```
fnames <-list.files("C:/Users/selva/Desktop/Lab_code/Full_files",pattern 
                         = '^La')# getting all the files from directory.
csv <- lapply(fnames,read.csv)  
source_DF <- do.call(rbind, csv)  # encountering error here as shown 
                                                               below
```

As you can see below, it has read all the files. When I use print(fnames), I am able to see the below output

[image]
[image: Error message]

Last file has 59 columns but my data has only 8 columns

[image]

I would like to rbind them successfully witghout any error and create a DF out of it. Please help

Comment: Will I not lose the header information then? Anyway I tried and it's still the same error

Comment: Can you check `csv` is it reading the files in list correctly? Does it have correct information with correct column names?

Comment: Oh yes, I was able to see that one of the csv file has 59 columns which is incorrect. Actually I only have only 8 columns. But it's reading empty columns beyond 8 as well.How do I stop/fix this? Please find the updated screenshot above. I am saving the csv sheet with data range selected (1st column to 8th column). How else can I get rid of this?

Comment: Assuming first 8 columns is what we want, can you try doing `csv[[14]] <- csv[[14]][1:8]` ? and then try out `source_DF <- do.call(rbind, csv)` ?

Comment: `source_DF <- do.call(rbind, lapply(csv, '[', 1:8))`

Comment: I pasted the data in new csv and was able to get rid of this. Thank you Ronak and jogo

Comment: @jogo - Can you please let me know what does the **'['** indicate in your comment ?

Comment: @SELVA It is the argument for the parameter `FUN=` so that the indexing function is called. see: `x <- 11:15; '['(x, 3) # result: x[3]`